# Radio buttons staying on even with values given

Tags: javascript

I create some radio buttons with typescript and load them to the page but the buttons stay active and won't turn off. I hope to eventually save the option that is chosen but have been stuck on this part.
poll.value is equal to something like "asdf" which should allow only one radio button to be clicked, but it doesn't.

```
    var pollPoll = document.createElement("div");
    var pollOptionA = document.createElement("input");
    pollOptionA.id = "optionA";
    pollOptionA.type = "radio";
    pollOptionA.value = poll.value;
    pollPoll.appendChild(pollOptionA);
    var optionA = document.createElement("span");
    optionA.innerHTML = poll.options[0];
    pollPoll.appendChild(optionA);
    var breakLine1 = document.createElement("br");
    pollPoll.appendChild(breakLine1);

    var pollOptionB = document.createElement("input");
    pollOptionB.id = "optionB";
    pollOptionB.type = "radio";
    pollOptionB.value = poll.value;
    pollPoll.appendChild(pollOptionB);
    var optionB = document.createElement("span");
    optionB.innerHTML = poll.options[1];
    pollPoll.appendChild(optionB);
    var breakLine2 = document.createElement("br");
    pollPoll.appendChild(breakLine2);

    var pollOptionC = document.createElement("input");
    pollOptionC.id = "optionC";
    pollOptionC.type = "radio";
    pollOptionC.value = poll.value;
    pollPoll.appendChild(pollOptionC);
    var optionC = document.createElement("span");
    optionC.innerHTML = poll.options[2];
    pollPoll.appendChild(optionC);
    var breakLine3 = document.createElement("br");
    pollPoll.appendChild(breakLine3);

    var pollOptionD = document.createElement("input");
    pollOptionD.id = "optionD";
    pollOptionD.type = "radio";
    pollOptionD.value = poll.value;
    pollPoll.appendChild(pollOptionD);
    var optionD = document.createElement("span");
    optionD.innerHTML = poll.options[3];
    pollPoll.appendChild(optionD);
    var breakLine4 = document.createElement("br");
    pollPoll.appendChild(breakLine4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons need a name to function properly. The name is used to logically group the elements so they toggle properly. Add a name to your elements, the same name for the same group (pollOptionA.name = "pollOption") and it will work for you. You can read up more on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!

Comment: @ZarenWienclaw glad to hear, please remember to mark this as the answer so it can help people in the future as well as give me credit for helping out.